# Get the attribute name from the class, not from an object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot

I'm learning programming on a project https://github.com/Netflix/genie/blob/master/genie-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/genie/core/jpa/specifications/JpaJobSpecs.java. 
I'm programming in my app to download movies by title, genre, etc. I found an interesting way to construct an advanced command in this Netflix project. However, I have a problem with retrieving the attribute name. 
In the Netflix project, the attribute names are used to retrieve the attributes `JobEntity_`, I do not know where the sign came from `_`, because there is no class with this sign in the project. By this problem I can not finish the program.

Comment: Its a naming pattern for JPA Metamodel. Classes are usually autogenerated

Comment: I first meet this. Where is the metamodel built?

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html